# PayPal Payment gateway (sandbox )working fine on local host but getting error on live server in codeignitor

Tags: codeigniter, paypal

I am getting this error when I make a payment on live server but its working on localhost

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/x20r1g9ksc5m/public_html/trizolo.com/application/libraries/paypal-php-sdk/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php72/usr/share/pear') in /home/x20r1g9ksc5m/public_html/trizolo.com/application/controllers/Paypal.php on line 3

```
require_once(APPPATH . 'libraries/paypal-php-sdk/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/sample/bootstrap.php'); // require paypal files
```

Comment: I am using this code.. please check this link

http://webeasystep.com/blog/view_article/paypal_payment_gateway_integration_in_codeigniter

Comment: You should provide *relevant* code (your code, your controller, not the site you used as an example). It's impossible to help you and even try to understand what may be wrong with your code if we can't see that :) At this point, I'd suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) thoroughly